# xcode start an application on a different view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, ios-4.2

I am building an application and the easiest way to set up a main menu was to make a new file.

I called it MainMenu.h/.m/.xib

I went into the info.plist and tried changing MainWindow to MainMenu, didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try connecting the new window to the window object in the app delegate.